# Generate Streamplot With 2D Raster Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, python-xarray

I am attempting to generate a streamplot in Matplotlib using u-component & v-component winds from a gridded analysis, and am unsure how to compile these arrays into the Streamplot function. These data are two-dimensional, in GeoTIFF format, and is read into Python using xarray/rioxarray as follows:

```
import rioxarray as rxr
import numpy as np
ugrd = '/path/to/file/rtma2p5_ucomp.tif'
vgrd = '/path/to/file/rtma2p5_vcomp.tif'
        
ucomp = rxr.open_rasterio(ugrd)
ux, uy = np.meshgrid(ucomp['x'], ucomp['y'])
vcomp = rxr.open_rasterio(vgrd)
vx, vy = np.meshgrid(vcomp['x'], vcomp['y'])
     
X, Y = ucomp['x'], ucomp['y']
        
# Uncertainty on U,V
stream = plt.streamplot(X,Y,U,V)
```

From the Streamplot documentation, I can leverage rioxarray to pass the 1-dimensional grid arrays as the X & Y arguments for the function. However, I am uncertain how to approach the U & V components, given both are 2-dimensional meshed into x and y components after executing numpy meshgrid.

What additional steps can I take to pass each two-dimensional wind component into the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is definitely to use [`xarray.Dataset.plot.streamplot`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.plot.streamplot.html):

```py
ds = xr.Dataset({'u': ucomp, 'v': 'vcomp'})
ds.plot.streamplot(x="x", y="y", u="u", v="v")
```

If you want to instead with matplotlib, you're nearly there! As you mention, the arguments do need to be 1D arrays. [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is already producing the x and y 2D coordinate labels (you've assigned them to `ux, uy` and also `vx, vy` - I assume these are the same). So for each `(x, y)` point indexing `ucomp` and `vcomp`, there is a correponding set of coordinates `(ux[i, j], uy[i, j])`. This allows you to reshape all four arrays to get the inputs you need:

```py
plt.streamplot(
    ux.ravel(),
    uy.ravel(),
    ucomp.values.ravel(),
    vcomp.values.ravel(),
)
```

Comment: thank you for the direction! A follow-up question, I get the error downstream that the DataArrays (both ucomp & vcomp) generated from opening the GeoTIFF **do not** contain the attribute ravel(). Any suggestions on how I can flatten these DataArrays?

Comment: oh my bad. you'd need `ucomp.values.ravel()` and similarly for `vcomp`. [`np.ndarray.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) is a numpy function.

Comment: No worries, discovered this moments after writing the previous response. I will accept your answer, I appreciate your help!